# Using Blendshapes as animationframes in Spark AR to animate Mesh Object

Tags: javascript, animation, augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

I am trying to animate a 3D object in spark AR. For you to understand what I'm trying to do, I'll explain exactly what I did in blender, how I imported it in spark and what I did there. It's my first spark AR project and I'm not used to the reactive programming yet, so sorry if I made rookie mistakes there.

So let's go through it step by step:

1. First I created a sphere in blender and manipulated it's shape with a diplace modifier and a cloud texture. I animated the displacement by linking the texture coordinates to an empty object, that i keyframed so i get a looping deformation animation.
2. Then I converted the animation frames to keyframed shapekeys by exporting it from blender as an .mdd file, reimporting and applying it to the sphere object. So I have one shapekey for every frame of the animation in blender.
3. I exported the object as a .fbx File and imported it into spark AR studio. So far everything worked exactly as a hoped it would. I have the object in spark with all the attached shapekeys as blendshapes of the mesh object. I tested every single one of the blendshapes by setting all of them to 0 and then setting them to 100% seperately and they all work perfectly.
   [Screenshot of my spark Project with the mesh object selected and the blendshapes listed to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYfX6.jpg)
4. Now I figured I could recreate the loop animation that I did in blender by cycling through the blendshapes and setting them to 1 and back to 0 frame by frame. So here is what I tried in script:

Require the modules I need:

```
const Animation = require('Animation');
const Scene = require('Scene');
const D = require('Diagnostics');
const Reactive = require('Reactive');
```

Load the assets from the spark project (in this case I only need the Meshobject, that I named Hoverball.001):

```
(async function () {
  // Enables async/await in JS [part 1]

  // Access scene objects
  const loadAssets = await Promise.all(
    [
    Scene.root.findFirst("Hoverball.001"),
    ]
  )
```

Then I called a function and give it the assets I loaded in the promise as a parameter. I assign the loaded meshobject to a variable and use the getBlendShapes()-Method to get an array filled with all the Blendshapes in the Meshobject.

```
.then(function(assets){
    const hoverBall = assets[0];
    const hoverBallShapes = hoverBall.getBlendShapes();
```

Then I create a Loop Animation with a frame transition by using a timeDriver and a frame-sampler, starting the timedriver right away and combining both the driver and the sampler in an animation.

```
    const timeDriverParameters = {
      durationMilliseconds: 10000,
      loopCount: Infinity,
      mirror: false
    }

    const timeDriver = Animation.timeDriver(timeDriverParameters);
    timeDriver.start();
    const frameSampler = Animation.samplers.frame(240,0);
    const frameAnimation = Animation.animate(timeDriver, frameSampler);
```

Now a assign the frameAnimation to a variable to get the current Frame of the Loop animation. (This step might be a bit useless, but I wanted to have a variable that helps me understand what I'm dealing with). So now I have the current Frame as a scalarSignal in my currentFrame Variable and I use that variable to access the weight Property of the Blendshape corresponding to the current frame of the animation, change it to 1 and at the same time setting the weight of the Blendshape corresponding to the previous frame to 0. Obviously the first frame works a bit different then the rest, because I have to set the last frame (in this cas frame 239) to 0. To achieve that, I check if the current frame is 0. I could get the index if the last frame from the frame count that I set in the sampler, but I didn't want to overcomplicate things, so I just hard coded the 239 in here.

```
    const currentFrame = frameAnimation; 

    if (currentFrame.pinLastValue() === 0) {
      D.log('condition true');
      hoverBallShapes._value[239].weight = Reactive.val(0);
      D.log('frame 239: ' + hoverBallShapes._value[239].weight.pinLastValue());
      hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight = Reactive.val(1);
      D.log('frame ' + currentFrame.pinLastValue() + ': ' + hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight.pinLastValue());
    }
    else {
      D.log('condition false');
      hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue() - 1].weight = Reactive.val(0);
      D.log('frame ' + (currentFrame.pinLastValue() - 1) + ': ' + hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight.pinLastValue());
      hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight = Reactive.val(1);
      D.log('frame ' + currentFrame.pinLastValue() + ': ' + hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight.pinLastValue());
    }
  });

})(); // Enables async/await in JS [part 2]
```

I did a bunch of console logs there to see whats happening and the script does pretty much what I wanted. It accesses the Blendshapes weight and changes it to 1, changing the shape of the meshobject in the viewport. However, it does not loop or cycle through all the blendshapes. It just does the first frame and then stops. When I set the start frame to like 200 or something, it just does it once for frame 200. Basically, my code works fine, the frame 200 Blendshape is even set to 1 and the shape changes to the Blendshape but I just can't figure out how I get my script to do the weight change for every frame and not just once for the first frame it gets and then stop doing anything at all. Maybe I'm going at this all wrong and there's an easier way to loop through the blendshapes, but I thought my approach was pretty straightforward and there's so little missing for it to work. So, if anyone has an Idea how to make it work, please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself and wanted to let others know, how I did it.

Basically, this part doesn't work, because the pinLastValue-Method, that I need to build the condition for the if-else-statement gets the value at one specific point in time and makes it a static value, which is in this case the value 0.

```
if (currentFrame.pinLastValue() === 0) {
    D.log('condition true');
    hoverBallShapes._value[239].weight = Reactive.val(0);
    D.log('frame 239: ' + hoverBallShapes._value[239].weight.pinLastValue());
    hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight = Reactive.val(1);
    D.log('frame ' + currentFrame.pinLastValue() + ': ' + hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight.pinLastValue());
}
else {
    D.log('condition false');
    hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue() - 1].weight = Reactive.val(0);
    D.log('frame ' + (currentFrame.pinLastValue() - 1) + ': ' + hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight.pinLastValue());
    hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight = Reactive.val(1);
    D.log('frame ' + currentFrame.pinLastValue() + ': ' + hoverBallShapes._value[currentFrame.pinLastValue()].weight.pinLastValue());
}
```

Instead in reactive programming, I need to subscribe a function to a stream of values, without taking one value out of the stream and making it a static value in that process. So here's what I did to make it work:

```
//Subscribe Shapefunction to Animation
currentFrame.monitor().subscribe(function(event) {
    hoverBallShapes._value[event.oldValue].weight = Reactive.val(0);
    hoverBallShapes._value[event.newValue].weight = Reactive.val(1);
});
```

I use the .monitor()-Method of the [ScalarSignal-Class](https://sparkar-community.gitbook.io/docs/reactivemodule/scalarsignal) to watch for changes in the scalarSignal-Value of the Animation-object. So every time the frame updates, the monitor()-method creates an [EventSource](https://sparkar-community.gitbook.io/docs/reactivemodule/eventsource) with the format `{'oldValue': val, 'newValue': val}`, where the old value is stored as 'oldValue' and the new value is stored as 'newValue'.
Now I subscribe a function to the monitor()-Method and pass the event, that is emitted by the monitor()-Method as a parameter to the function.
Inside the function I can now access the value of the previous frame and the value of the curent frame by accessing the properties of the passed eventSource-Object with `event.oldValue` and `event.newValue` and use them as keys to access the blendshape corresponding to the previous and current frame and change their weight-property.
Because I subscribed the function to the monitor()-Method of the currentFrame-Object (which is of the scalarSignal-class), I don't need to use imparative programming and static values. Instead the function "listens" to the stream and runs everytime, the value of the scalarSignal changes.

This use of the monitor()-Method is, however, not encouraged by the spar AR devs and the heavy use of hundreds of complex blendshapes (resulting in a bigger filesize - 13mb for me, which is tiny for a sophisticated 3D-object, but not tiny enough for instagrams 4MB-maximum), means that it is most likely not possible to use an effect like this in an instagram filter. It works fine with the sparkAR-player though and could be used in a custom app or web-app.